# Haxe Asynchronously Read Local File?

Tags: file, ipc, haxe

I need to do IPC with another app. That app sends data and my Haxe app receives. For some reason my choice narrows down to the file system.

My idea is to have the other app keep updating a file, and my Haxe app keeps reading from that file. The problem is I keep getting the same value, although the data file is changing. I assume I need some asynchronous reader to get the updated file, but what should I use?

Here's my code:

```
var tmpWaveRaw = sys.io.File.getContent("assets/wave.txt");
trace(tmpWaveRaw); //always stays the same when the app is running, but changes when the app restarts.
```

Thanks!

**Update:**
Here's an experiment I just did:

1. Have my code keeps printing modified time of the file every 100ms.
2. Let the other application modify the file and stop.
3. Start my application. Now it's printing the correct modified time, and it is consistent with my OS's file stat.
4. Let the other application modify the file again. Close.
5. My application still prints the old modified time, not consistent with my OS's file stat.

Comment: Are you getting the content of the file each time it changes?

Comment: @JustoDelgado No. I can only get the same value while the app is running, regardless if the file is changing or not.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you need to read again the file after it changes:

```
var running = true;
var last = sys.FileSystem.stat("test.txt");
while (running) {
    var now = sys.FileSystem.stat("test.txt");
    if (last.mtime.getTime() != now.mtime.getTime()) {
        last = now;
        trace(sys.io.File.getContent("test.txt"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's weird, but the mtimes doesn't change either.

Comment: The file has to be closed/saved by your other application so the file content gets saved into disk and you can get the changes with Haxe.

Comment: I guess the file content does get saved into disk, because I can see the Modified Time and other changes on my OS's file browser, even when the other application is re-opening and re-writing the file.